# Score of RFECV() in python scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Scikit-learn library supports recursive feature elimination(RFE) and its cross validation version(RFECV). RFECV is very useful for me it selects small features, but I wonder how cross validation of RFE is done.

RFE is way to reduce least important features features. So I thought RFECV will calculate cross validation score removing feature 1 by 1.

But if cross validation is used, I think each fold will select other features for their least important because data is different.
Does someone know how feature is removed in RFECV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cross validation is done on the **number of features**. Each CV iteration updates the score for each number of removed features.

It then picks a number `n_features_to_select` of features to keep, based on the score, and uses RFE on the complete dataset keeping only `n_features_to_select` features.

From the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c957249/sklearn/feature_selection/rfe.py#L415):

```
for n, (train, test) in enumerate(cv):
    X_train, y_train = _safe_split(self.estimator, X, y, train)
    X_test, y_test = _safe_split(self.estimator, X, y, test, train)

    rfe = RFE(estimator=self.estimator,
              n_features_to_select=n_features_to_select,
              step=self.step, estimator_params=self.estimator_params,
              verbose=self.verbose - 1)

    rfe._fit(X_train, y_train, lambda estimator, features:
             _score(estimator, X_test[:, features], y_test, scorer))
    scores.append(np.array(rfe.scores_[::-1]).reshape(1, -1))
scores = np.sum(np.concatenate(scores, 0), 0)
# The index in 'scores' when 'n_features' features are selected
n_feature_index = np.ceil((n_features - n_features_to_select) /
                          float(self.step))
n_features_to_select = max(n_features_to_select,
                           n_features - ((n_feature_index -
                                         np.argmax(scores)) *
                                         self.step))
# Re-execute an elimination with best_k over the whole set
rfe = RFE(estimator=self.estimator,
          n_features_to_select=n_features_to_select,
          step=self.step, estimator_params=self.estimator_params)
rfe.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I did not understand the meaning of 'cross validation on number of features'. What I wanted to know was 'how to make order for elimination. As I understand the code, at first RFE run on whole dataset ordering. (So only 1 test is done for making order) Then score is tested for each cross validation, then delete n feature using that order, and so on. Am I right?

Comment: @z991 Not exactly. The RFE is run on each CV fold, and we keep the mean of each feature score across all CV folds. We then use the mean score to compute the number of features to remove, the remove that number of features using the whole dataset.

Comment: Now I understood the flow. Thank you very much!